# What's the best way to post data from Django?

Tags: django

Newcomer to django so bere with me here...

In my django app one of my urls accepts a paramater called receipt. I need to retrieve the receipt from the url and post it to a external web service. No database is involved in any of this. To user simply goes to http://myapp.com/receipt?=receipt=somereceipt . I read the receipt and then post it to a external web service.

I implemented this by using urllib2 and it works fine.

Is there a better way to make post requests from Django, or is using urllib2 ok? Will urllib2 scale to many requests?

Thanks,

-David

Comment: You need to be a bit more detailed on what your feature/functionality actually needs to do and in what conditions, as it's pretty unclear. From what I understand, some Python/Django code (ex. in management command) which takes the receipt info directly from the database through the ORM and then posts it to the external web service should be much more efficient.

Comment: sorry, i've edited it to be a bit more clear

Comment: Quick answer: if it's working fine now, you're good. Don't get bogged down in premature optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib2` sounds like a completely reasonable way to solve your problem. However you might want to take a look at the `requests` library: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html It wraps `urllib2` so that you can make the HTTP requests you want and maintain your sanity.

Comment: +1 for requests. Save your sanity and use it. Put it under your pillow for sweet dreams.